# Binning and Visualization with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, cut, binning

So I'm trying to make an age interval column for my dataframe:

```
df['age_interval'] = pd.cut(x=df['Age'], bins=[18, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 60], include_lowest=True)
```

And I added my graph:

[image: Visualization]

**Problem:** In the visualization the [18-22] bin is displayed as [17.99-22].

**What I want:** I want it to display [18-22].

Below is the plot code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
dist = sns.barplot(x=ibm_ages.index, y=ibm_ages.values, color='blue')
dist.set_title('IBM Age Distribution', fontsize = 24)
dist.set_xlabel('Age Range', fontsize=18)
dist.set_ylabel('Total Count', fontsize=18)

sizes=[]
for p in dist.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    sizes.append(height)
    dist.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height + 5,
            '{:1.2f}%'.format(height/total*100),
            ha="center", fontsize= 8) 

plt.tight_layout(h_pad=3)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's a float64 Type and you want an integer try:

```
import numpy as np
df['age_interval'] = pd.cut(x=df['Age'].astype('Int64'), bins=[18, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 60], include_lowest=True)
```

you can use .astype('Int64') whenever you want to convert float64 to Int64

Comment: `CategoricalDtype(categories=[(17.999, 22.0], (22.0, 27.0], (27.0, 32.0], (32.0, 37.0], (37.0, 42.0], (42.0, 47.0], (47.0, 52.0], (52.0, 57.0], (57.0, 60.0]],ordered=True)` 
Even though I've changed it to int64, the dtype is still a float.

Comment: _int : Defines the number of equal-width bins in the range of x. The range of x is extended by .1% on each side to include the minimum and maximum values of x._

this was on the pandas doc

Answer (score 1):

A bar plot is misleading here, because the bins do not have equal width. Age is a continuous variable. Why obscure the fact that the bins border each other?

This is precisely the setting where a histogram is useful. You can still customize the bins and set the tick marks accordingly. The other plot customizations also work all the same.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.normal(35, 10, 1000)})
bins = [18, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 60]

ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='Age', bins=bins)
ax.set_xticks(bins)
```

[image: Age histogram]